# Firestore rules depending on document attribute

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Having read through the documentation, I believe the rules below should allow me to lock all documents inside a database to their respective owners. So I have a property on a document called owner, which should compare the auth uid and set permissions based on the ownership of the document. I'm still receiving an `Insufficient permissions` error though. Someone can explain to me why this is happening?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Let's assume I have a `task` object in a todo app. All the tasks are stored in the same tasks collection: `/databases/{database}/documents/tasks/*`

```
tasks/arYBG3ydXW: {
  title: 'A task',
  owner: uid,
}
```

I want to make sure that only the owner of the document can read or edit that document. However, first error already happens when trying to read the tasks from the collection. To be clear: I created some documents without rules setup, so I was initially able to write to the database without enforcing restrictions.

```
query(collection(db, 'tasks'), where('owner', '==', uid))
```

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.3): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: {"code":"permission-denied","name":"FirebaseError"}

---

Also, I'm questioning now whether this is the best way to structure my data in this scenario. What would you consider to be "best-practice", approach 1 or 2 (assuming multiple users are going to access the same database)?

```
Approach 1: (with a prop indicating to whom a doc belongs)
/databases/{database}/documents/tasks/*.{uid}
/databases/{database}/documents/workspaces/*.{uid}
...

Approach 2: (all docs for a user in a separate collection)
/databases/{database}/documents/uid/{tasks},{workspaces}, ...
```

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own, but only become active once you execute code against them. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code with which you get that error?

Comment: I've made some edits. Would that be enough to understand what's going on? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: At first glance that code looks fine, but it depends on how you determine the value `uid`. I recommend using `getAuth().currentUser.uid` to ensure you're passing in the same value tht your rules check.

Comment: I do actually use that to retrieve the uid. Could it be a that a single document lacks the owner prop and therefore firestore throws an error, preventing the loading of the rest?

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't be it. Firebase doesn't actually check the individual documents (as that would never scale), but instead just checks whether you code stays within the restriction o your rules. Since the `where('owner', '==', uid)` condition you pass matches what the rules check, that should pass. I'm not sure what else could be going wrong, hence my suggestion to look up the UID exactly when this query executes (rather than assigning the UID to a variable before it).

Comment: Oh looking up the UID at query execution time actually works, thanks for that. Do you happen to have any recommendation on the second part of the questions, around setting up the document structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Frank in the comments from the original question, looking up the UID at execution time fixes the issue.

So instead of doing this:

`query(collection(db, 'tasks'), where('owner', '==', uid))`

do this:

`query(collection(db, 'tasks'), where('owner', '==', getAuth().currentUser.uid))`